# Preg_match to allow for a single quote character in username

Tags: php, regex

My code:

`preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%^&_ -\\\']{3,48}$/", $hostname)`

I want the site to accept user names like: John's Pub. At the moment this kind of works because it allows for single quote (') but it also accepts (\).

I have tried single quote on it's own, with 1 \ and 2 \ but none of this works.

Comment: Thank you both. Unfortunately none of the above options work. I have fairly simple requirements: min 3 letters and then possible numbers and possible special characters including '. I'm starting to think that there may be something wrong elsewhere but not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

To be specific to your problem you can try this:

```
preg_match('/\A(\w*[\'\(\)]*\w*\s*\w*)+\z/', $$hostname);
```

Where:

- `\A` means Start of String
- `\w` means Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
- `*`  means 0 or more than 0 time(of prefix of `*`, here prefix is `\w`)
- `\'` means allow character `'` similarly  `\(` and `\)` is for defining allowed character
- `[]` is group operator
- `\s` is for whitespace
- `\z` is for end of String

Hope this will help

Edit:
[You can try your custom regex here as well](https://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems:

1. Use case insensitive flag instead of `[A-Za-z]`
2. You cannot put `-` in a `[]`. block it means range! Escape it `\-`.
3. Don't use `\\\'` it means a `\` and `'` which leads to nothing right!
4. use `\w` instead of `0-9A-Za-z`. It's simpler.

Try this:

```
preg_match("/^[\w!@#$%^&_ \-']{3,48}$/i", $hostname)
```

If you want to allow `\` character too, use this:

```
preg_match("/^[\w!@#$%^&_ \-'\\\\]{3,48}$/i", $hostname)
```

If you want to allow `()` characters too, use this:

```
preg_match("/^[\w!@#$%^&_ \-'\(\)]{3,48}$/i", $hostname)
```

All Combined:

```
preg_match("/^[\w!@#$%^&_ \-'\(\)\\\\]{3,48}$/i", $hostname)
```